# jar file keeps loading and gives parse result

Tags: php

I have problem with my code..
I try to run Jar file in webserver. (MAMP)

When I post info to inputs it must choose folder and there is jar file and must run it, but browser keeps loading and 15sec later I get array result.

> Array69StartedParsed: 50Go on 50Parsed: 50Go on 100Parsed: 50Go on 150Parsed: 50Go on 200Parsed: 50Go on 250Parsed: 50Go on 300Parsed: 50Go on 350Parsed: 50Go on 400Parsed: 50Go on 450Parsed: 50Go on 500Parsed: 50Go on 550Parsed: 50Go on 600Parsed: 50Go on 650Parsed: 50Go on 700Parsed: 50Go on 750Parsed: 50Go on 800Parsed: 50Go on 850Parsed: 50Go on 900Parsed: 50Go on 950Parsed: 50Go on 1000Parsed: 50Go on 1050Parsed: 50Go on 1100Parsed: 50Go on 1150Parsed: 50Go on 1200Parsed: 50Go on 1250Parsed: 50Go on 1300Parsed: 50Go on 1350Parsed: 50Go on 1400Parsed: 50Go on 1450Parsed: 50Go on 1500Parsed: 50Go on 1550Parsed: 40Go on 1600Parsed: 0OutParse time: 24958No cache

My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = "search_url=" . $_POST['vali1'] .  "\r\n" . "time=" . $_POST['vali2'] . "\r\n" . "email_to=" . $_POST['vali3'] .  "\r\n" . "email_from=" . $_POST['vali4'] . "\r\n" . "email_host=" . $_POST['vali5'] . "\r\n" . "email_subject=" . $_POST['vali6'] . "\r\n" . "email_content=" . ' \n';

    $date   = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Tallinn'));
    $time   = $date->format('d-m-YH:i');
    $time_m = preg_replace('/-|:/', null, $time);

    $source = "test";
    $dest   = $_POST['vali6'] . "_" . $time_m;


    mkdir($dest, 0755);
    foreach (
     $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
      new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
      \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item
    ) {
      if ($item->isDir()) {
        mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
      } else {
        copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
      }
    }
    file_put_contents($dest . '/config.properties', '');
    $ret = file_put_contents($dest . '/config.properties', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('<h4 style="color:red;">Error!</h4>');
    }
    else {
        echo "<h4 style='color:green;'>$ret writed into file</h4>";
    }   

    chdir($dest);
    exec('java -jar autosearch.jar', $result);
    echo $result;
    echo $count = count($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
    print($result[$i]);
    }

  }
  else {
    die('<h4 style="color:orange;">No data.</h4>');
  }
```

Config.properties is file for Java program what my inputs creates.

Java program isnt mine so I cant edit code.

I've tryed also shell_exec, but I cant get it work..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem with your code. You are running an external java application from your php script. This stalls your php script until the external application has completed running, after which you print out its output, line by line. It works just as expected. Can you please explain what it is that you expect to happen?

Comment: @AronCederholm it must run all the time, like background program, it like searches. But it stop all the time. I dont know how to get it work properly. If i click submit it starts loading. but it doesnt give how much data is writed into config file so it must start after folder is created.

Comment: Add `&> /dev/null &` to your command if you want it to run continuously in the background. That way it won't stop when your php script ends, and it won't output anything to php.

Comment: @AronCederholm `exec('java -jar autosearch.jar &> /dev/null', $result);` added this command and now I cant see is it starting jar file or not on task manager. And it gived me Array0 result...